# Wordpress and qTranslate - getting current language in functions.php

Tags: php, wordpress, qtranslate

I am using qTranslate plugin with my Wordpress site and now I have to detect the active language in the themes functions.php file. The detection function `qtrans_getLanguage()` is working, however, it always shows the default language (en) as active, even though I have it switched in the page itself. How can I detect the language in function file?

Answer (score 8):

This worked for me:

```
if (qtrans_getLanguage() == 'en') {
  // english
  print "Hello world!"; 
} elseif (qtrans_getLanguage() == 'es') {
  // spanish
  print "Hola Mundo!"; 
}
```

Notice that this has changed in **qTranslate X (the new version)**:

```
if (qtranxf_getLanguage() == 'en') {
  // english
  print "Hello world!"; 
} elseif (qtranxf_getLanguage() == 'es') {
  // spanish
  print "Hola Mundo!";
}
```

There is also some compatibility functions in the plugin options according to [this](https://wordpress.org/support/topic/undefined-function-qtrans_getlanguage)

**To apply this code you need some PHP knowledge, it is used to translate exact parts of your Wordpress Theme**

Comment: What do you need exactly? It really depends on where you want to apply the translation. You need to put it wherever you want to translate a particular part of your Wordpress Theme (in the php).

Answer (score 0):

use this :

```
if ( get_bloginfo('language')=='ar' )  
{  
//load css or js files for Arabic language as example  
}
```

replace 'ar' with yours